# Why does there appear to be an inconsistency with the DOS PSP's unformatted parameter area?

Tags: assembly, dos

For both MS-DOS and IBM-DOS, the latter of which I am using, starting at address 80h, there is a reserved portion in memory for command line arguments passed along. Address 80h is a counter for how long this is, and address 81h is where the arguments in ASCII begin. The problem is that this region of memory seems to rarely actually work as intended.

When I load into `debug.com` with the parameter `LOADME`, the memory looks a bit like this.

```
-D 80 8F
1039:0080  00 0D 4C 4F 41 44 4D 45-0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ..LOADME........
```

The inconsistency here is address 80H, which should contain a counter but evidently only reads out a 0 despite `LOADME` being there in its entirety. Things only become more inconsistent if I feed a larger parameter into the program. For comparison, here's how the parameter `LOADME NOW` looks.

```
-D 80 8F
1039:0080  04 20 4E 4F 57 0D 4D 45-20 4E 4F 57 0D 00 00 00  . NOW.ME NOW....
```

Now the counter reads 4, which is closer to being correct, but that's still not correct. Furthermore, `LOAD` has been dropped entirely from the parameter list. I've scrapped together two programs as well, one taken from StackOverflow and one of my own design. The StackOverflow program works flawlessly, able to output the correct input.

```
MOV AH, 40
MOV BX, 0001
XOR CH, CH
MOV CL, [0080]
MOV DX, 0081
INT 21 ; Write directly to device 1, with memory address 80h as your counter and your string beginning at 81
MOV AX, 4C00
INT 21 ; Exit
```

No matter what you feed this program, it will be able to output to the screen the exact data right back at you. Unfortunately, this is very limited in uses outside of making a copy of the echo command.

In turn, I've created this program which lets me copy the portion of memory at 81H and try to read it. This program does not work as intended, and mostly spits out gibberish data the moment you run it. It is possible that this due to a programming mistake since this is my first unguided attempt at a program, but it helps get my point across.

```
XOR AX, AX ; Clearing out the registers.
XOR BX, BX
XOR CX, CX
XOR DX, DX
MOV DX, 0300 ; A variable offset that I left unused
MOV AX, [0080] ; The counter
MOV BX, 0080 ; The current read position
ADD BX, 01; Begin loop
MOV CX, [BX]
ADD BX, 0300 ; Jump to our offset
MOV [BX], CX
SUB BX, 0300 ; Remove our offset in memory. 
DEC AX
JNZ 0111
ADD BX, 0301 ; Loop ended here.
MOV CX, 0024 ; Now, at the end of the string, add a $.
MOV [BX], CX
MOV AH, 09
MOV BX, 301
INT 21 ; Execute "display string"
MOV AX, 4C
INT 21 ; End program
```

It will certainly read where the parameter is, but ignoring the fact that it tends to overwrite where the argument is, it doesn't appear to do so consistently, flashing only snippets of what I expect the output to be before erasing them.

Is this really a problem with IBM-DOS, or is `debug.com` playing tricks on me and I'm a bad programmer?

Comment: Hey, by the ways, if someone knows where the StackOverflow program came from, it would be good to know. I want to credit them, but the problem is that someone else showed me it in person, and I didn't catch the name of the problem.

Comment: Isn't `LOADME` the name of your program? That does not count as a parameter, hence the zero in the first case. The 4 in the second case includes the space and the `NOW`. Your code is wrong at least because you do `MOV AX, [0080]` with `AX` being a 16 bit register but the counter being 8 bits only. Same goes for the characters of the argument you don't want to use `CX`. Adding and subtracting the `0300` seems like a waste.

Comment: The original Debug (or my current recreation of most of it in free software, at https://pushbx.org/ecm/download/msdebug.zip ) does play some tricks **if** you use its N command. If you just pass a program name and a following command line tail to the Debug command however it will work as you should expect. The first word (`LOADME`) is the program name, not part of your debuggee client's command line tail (`NOW`). There are other ways to retrieve the program's command name, either in the MCB name or after the double NUL that terminates your environment block.

Comment: @Jester `LOADME` is a placeholder being fed into debug.com to demonstrate the problem I'm encountering. The name's not really relevant, just the fact that the unformatted region is incorrect when I investigate it.
Also, thanks for the advice on assembly. I'm very new to it so every little bit helps. Just a thing about my code:`MOV CX, 24` is only implemented as a quick patch to the fact you can't do `MOV [BX], 24`, otherwise I would've done that instead.

Comment: @ecm I don't think I'm picking up what you're putting down. Are you saying that debug.com is distorting what I'm expecting to see in the parameter region? I'm calling these as `debug.com LOADME` and `debug.com LOADME NOW` respectively. I am not using the N command to "load" these nonexistent files.

Comment: @Missingno50 There are two different processes at play. You think that Debug should receive `LOADME NOW` in its command line tail area (at its PSP:80h). However, what you are inspecting is the client's command line tail, which is created by Debug based on what the tail is (`NOW`) after a client program name (`LOADME`). It is expected that the program name should not occur in the client PSP's command line tail buffer. The remainders that you see after the empty string or `NOW` is just the uninitialised trail of the buffer.

Comment: @Missingno50 The N command is not for "loading" but rather for setting the command line tail and the program filename to load from. The L command is what is for loading. When you pass a program name and command line to the Debug command, this is handled similarly (but not the same) as if you entered an N command and an L command.

Comment: @Missingno50 `MOV [BX], 24` is not allowed because you didn't specify a size keyword for the memory operand. Try `mov byte [bx], 24` or `mov word [bx], 24`

Comment: @ecm I was not aware of the existence of the byte keyword. Thank you for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, actually this works correctly because

80h - Number of bytes on command-line

81h–FFh - Command-line tail (terminated by a 0Dh)

In first example 0Dh offset is 81h so 80h = 0

In second example 0Dh offset is 85h so 80h = 4

LOADME is not program name found in current directory.

debug programname params

---

Update 1:

`Debug LOADME`

Offset 81h looks like:

`(20h space)LOADME(0dh)`

Then system checks if LOADME is correct path to file. It is not so check if params exists? No, there is nothing more so 0dh is printed at 81h.

`(0dh)LOADME(0dh)`

---

`Debug LOADME NOW`

Offset 81h looks like:

`(20h space)LOADME(20h space)NOW(0dh)`

LOADME is not correct path to file so print this at 81h = 0dh, now buffer looks like:

`(0dh)LOADME(20h space)NOW(0dh)`

and check next input which is (20h space)NOW(0dh). So override, starting from 81h.

`(20h space)NOW(0dh)ME(20h space)NOW(0dh)`

---

Update 2:

I don't know what to add more. I can write things but if this will be Your answer You looking for?

DOS can load and execute two types of files, com and exe. Executed program with its environment is called process.
DOS can run one process at a time. Except of resident programs which are in memory. Process can call another
process temporarily suspending its work. And then programs create hierarchy of parent-child processes. In most cases parent will be command.com. Offset 16h in PSP shows segment of parent process so if I run debug.exe parent process segment is 0b18 (command.com)

`C:>debug.exe
-d 0
1181:0000  CD 20 FF 9F 00 9A EE FE-1D F0 4F 03 E5 0B 8A 03
1181:0010  E5 0B 17 03 E5 0B 18 0B-01 01 01 00 02 FF FF FF
1181:0020  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF-FF FF FF FF 20 09 4E 01
...
1181:0080  00 0D 63 6F 6D 6D 61 6E-64 2E 63 6F 6D 0D 65 79`

And if I check segment 0b18 indeed this is PSP of command.com. Parent process segment is 0b18 meaning that command.com has no parent process. Points to itself.

`0B18:0000  CD 20 FF 9F 00 9A F0 FE-1D F0 7E 01 18 0B 4A 01
0B18:0010  18 0B 55 01 18 0B 18 0B-01 01 01 00 02 FF FF FF
0B18:0020  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF-FF FF FF FF C3 0B F2 05
...
1181:0080  00 0D 63 6F 6D 6D 61 6E-64 2E 63 6F 6D 0D 65 79`

And there is something called DTA (Disk transfer area)

`Source Wikipedia`

The initial address for the DTA was set to overlay the area in the PSP (at address 0x80) where the command line arguments were stored, such that a program needed to parse this area for command line arguments before invoking DOS functions that made use of the DTA (such as reading in a file record), unless the program took care to change the address of the DTA to some other memory region (or not use the DTA/FCB functions altogether, which soon became deprecated in favour of file handles).

You can change this with `ah=1ah int 21h` and ask for DTA adress `ah=2fh int 21h`. Just what I found, never tested this functions.

---

Update 3:

If I run `debug testcode.exe -a abc -3` memory dump looks like this:

`0BA0:0000  CD 20 FF 9F 00 9A F0 FE-1D F0 4F 03 9A 05 8A 03
0BA0:0010  9A 05 17 03 9A 05 89 05-01 01 01 00 02 FF FF FF
0BA0:0020  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF-FF FF FF FF 47 0B 4C 01
.....
0BA0:0080  0A 20 2D 61 20 61 62 63-20 2D 33 0D 78 65 20 2D  . -a abc -3.xe -`

This is testcode.exe, at offset 81h we can see exact list of parameters.
Parent process is located here **05 89** and it is debug.exe At offset 81h are debug's parameters.

`0589:0000  CD 20 FF 9F 00 9A F0 FE-1D F0 DE 01 1E 04 4B 01
0589:0010  1E 04 56 01 1E 04 1E 04-01 01 01 00 02 FF FF FF
0589:0020  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF-FF FF FF FF 2F 05 B9 49

.....
0589:0080  17 20 74 65 73 74 63 6F-64 65 2E 65 78 65 20 2D  . testcode.exe -
0589:0090  61 20 61 62 63 20 2D 33-0D 20 54 33 0D 74 2E 65  a abc -3. T3.t.e`

Parent process of debug is located here **04 1E** and it is cmd.exe because I ran this under windows this time.

`041E:0000  CD 20 FF 9F 00 9A F0 FE-1D F0 7F 01 1E 04 4B 01
041E:0010  1E 04 56 01 1E 04 1E 04-01 01 01 00 02 FF FF FF
041E:0020  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF-FF FF FF FF C9 04 FA 05
.....
041E:0080  17 20 74 65 73 74 63 6F-64 65 2E 65 78 65 20 2D  . testcode.exe -
041E:0090  61 20 61 62 63 20 2D 33-0D 20 54 33 0D 74 2E 65  a abc -3. T3.t.e`

Comment: Hi @0Signal! Do you mind clarifying something for me? "LOADME" is the parameter I fed into debug.com. Are you saying that debug.com is manipulating that space in memory and thus that's why the counter and fed parameters are all wrong?

Comment: I don't know internal structure of debug and what is going on inside code. How debug processes given filename/parameters. I just see output. This is correct pattern `DEBUG [[drive:][path] filename [parameters]]` so after debug should be correct path to file. If not maybe operating system recognize this and put at offset 81h value 0dh and if You put more than one param like LOADME NOW so LOADME is wrong path to file and NOW is parameter and 0Dh after that.

Comment: Well, according to the [Tandy 1000 Programmer's Reference,](http://ftp.oldskool.org/pub/tvdog/tandy1000/documents/1kprog.zip) the space after 80H should include ALL data inputted after the call to the file(`debug.com` in this case,) and 80H is the counter how long this string of data is. That's why I'm confused about what I'm seeing.

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment. The information is found on PDF pages 157 and 159.

Comment: "An unformatted parameter area at 81h contains all the characters typed after the command". It looks like after pressing enter all characters are first written to offset 81h and then system checks what is what. So thats why data is overriden.

Comment: I edited my answer. Just how system maybe processes this input. Call Bill Gates and ask him xD

Comment: @Missingno50 debug.com has its own PSP, you are looking at the one from the loaded program

Comment: Okay, this is good to know, thanks @Sebastian, and this means this is my answer, but 0Signal, can you try to word it a little better? Maybe describe it as "the memory you can inspect with debug.com is separate, and drops the initial parameter when loading from the command prompt." Or something, I don't know. It just feels a bit confusing to read and it took me a few tries before I saw Sebastian's comment. If you don't want to, let me know and I'll still mark it as my answer.

Comment: I added some info. Update 2.

Comment: Use ```code formatting``` to post code, not pictures of text.  Running DOS inside an emulator like DOSBox, Bochs, or a VM, should make it possible to get text-mode screen contents in a terminal window you can copy/paste from.  If you're going to make a hobby of writing Stack Overflow answers like I do, I'd recommend getting your system set up so you can copy/paste terminal contents properly for the environment you want to write answers about.

Comment: Use triple backticks for code blocks.   See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . (You can also click edit on any existing post to see the markdown, if you want to see how something was done.)

Comment: How to place bold text inside code blocks?

Comment: You can't with markdown code blocks, unfortunately.  Everything is literal inside them.  IIRC, it might be possible with HTML `<pre>` code blocks, using other HTML tags for formatting.  Normally it's possible to indicate interesting things with comments or whatever, but for something in the middle of a hexdump there isn't a good way other than a picture of text, which sucks for some readers (e.g. blind users with screen-readers, or people behind a corporate firewall that block imgur.)  The literal `**` inside the hex dump kind of works for visual highlighting here.

Comment: So the parent process of the shown PSP, after starting debug.exe is not debug.exe? Or only when loading a .com file? I was thinking, that debug.exe, when started without parameters, configures the memory as if you are writing/loading a .com file? And debug.exe itself would be the parent of this child process?

Comment: See update 3.  All is nested.  cmd -> debug -> testcode

Comment: My concern was that you weren't making it clear that `debug.com` was dropping the first parameter fed to it in the unformatted parameter area. `debug.com testing file` drops `testing` after loading because that's what `debug.com` does for you to streamline testing. That's why seeing `0` in 80h makes sense even if you have fed `debug.com` a singular parameter.

Comment: Eh, screw it. I'll just mark it as the answer. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: By the way @Missingno50 you can use MS-DOS Debug's N command to change the PSP (at current DS value) to hold exactly the command line passed to the N, not including the command letter "N" but including the program load pathname you specified. This ends up with what you expected, although it is still using the child PSP. I described this some in https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/msdebug.htm#interface-load (MSDebug's K command and lDebug's K and N commands do **not** work like this.) More description in https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/msdebug.htm#cmdn